# Colums from different tables with same name

Tags: mysql

Have the following code:

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name
FROM
```

Nothing I can do about the colum names (not my database design), how can I differenticate the two colums called 'name' in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use aliases -

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name AS gallery_name
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name AS folder_name
FROM
```

The keyword **AS** may be omitted - `tb_galleries.name gallery_name`

Answer (score 4):

You should give an alias for any column with the same name:

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name as Name1
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name as Differentname
FROM
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give them an alternative column name in your query while using `AS`.

Example:

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name AS 'tb_g_name'
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name AS 'tb_f_name'
FROM
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name AS name_1
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name AS name_2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name as Name1
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name as Name2
FROM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use column aliases to differentiate the names.

```
       Have the following code:

       SELECT a.*
       , tb_media.filename
       , tb_galleries.name  as gallery_name ---(or whatever name u want)
       , tb_media_iptc.description
       , tb_media_iptc.title
       , tb_media_iptc.headline
       , tb_folders.name as folder_name ---(or whatever name u want)
       FROM
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the AS keyword:

```
SELECT a.*
 , tb_media.filename
 , tb_galleries.name AS galleryName
 , tb_media_iptc.description
 , tb_media_iptc.title
 , tb_media_iptc.headline
 , tb_folders.name AS foldersName
FROM
```

This will change the displayname of the columns...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I don't understand why your answer got downvoted. I can only assume some sticklers didn't like the `**` marks around the `AS galleryName` parts.  It's occasionally a nuisance, but you can't easily add emphasis to code fragments.